# Selecting a specific row with a condition ? LibreOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have this LibreOffice calc file with raws with full of zero

```
raw1 raw2 raw3 raw4 raw5 raw6 raw7 raw8 raw9 
 0    0    0    0    C    0    0    0    0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    W    0
```

I want to print only the character inside the row, like this

```
Result 
  C
  W
```

I did try with 'if' condition

```
IF(CD2:CR16 = 1, CD2:CR16)
```

but it's give me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MATCH](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#MATCH) to find the column that contains a character, and then [INDEX](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDEX) to get the cell's value.

```
=INDEX(CD2:CR2, MATCH("[A-Z]", CD2:CR2, 0))
```

For this to work, go to Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> Calculate, and choose `Enable regular expressions in formulas`.

**EDIT**:

According to https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions, `[:print:]` represents any printable character, so it grabs the first zero, which is probably why it does not seem to do what you want.

To match one of several words, the regular expression should be like this:

```
"word1|word2|word3"
```

Or for any word consisting of one or more letters:

```
"[:alpha:]+"
```

**EDIT 2**:

To grab C and 8 from `0 0 C 0` and `8 0 0 0` respectively, use `"[A-Z1-9]"`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you already answered my question,but what if its not a character, a word I'm trying to use [:print:] from the manual but its not working

Comment: What type of word are you trying to match -- all letters or some special characters as well?  See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes both letter and numbers (digit and special character)

Comment: but the problem I have all the rows are zeros, so when I use [:alnum:] its give me a zero. For example 0 0 0 0  8 0 0 0 the answer is 0, it should be 8